# RenderTransform occurs after EntranceThemeTransition on a TextBlock

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm applying an `EntranceThemeTransition` animation to a `TextBlock`. The `TextBlock` has a style of `PageHeaderTextStyle` which has a `RenderTransform` in it. The issue I'm having is that the `RenderTransform` applies a `Translation` effect that doesn't actually render until after the animation is done playing. So, it looks weird because the animation scrolls the control in, and then suddenly the translation snaps the text in place. Does anyone know why this happens?

Is there a way to play the animation with the translation taken into account?

Transform:

```
<Setter Property="RenderTransform">
    <Setter.Value>
        <TranslateTransform X="-2" Y="8"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}">
    <TextBlock.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </TextBlock.Transitions>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just came up against exactly the same issue. The way to solve it is to *nest* the `TextBlock` one level away from the `Grid` with the transition on it, for example with a second `Grid`.

What happens is the transition applies a transform to each of its children, but any transform they may have had is replaced temporarily until after the animation completes, resulting in the nasty 'snap' when the original transform is applied afterwards.

In the following example, the transition will run, replacing the `TextBlock`'s transform, and then after the transition ends the original transform will be applied. You see the 'snap':

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <TextBlock Text="Header" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"
        Margin="0,0,0,40"/>
</Grid>
```

In the next example, the transition runs and the transform is applied to the `Grid`, leaving the `TextBlock`'s transform unaffected. No 'snap':

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Header" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"
            Margin="0,0,0,40"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From your words it just seems like the EntranceThemeTransition animates the transform of your TextBlock. The simplest way around that would be to either put the entrance transition on a parent element, or put the transform on one. You could simply wrap your TextBlock in a Grid to do it.

Comment: Hi Filip, thanks for the response. I tried putting the TextBlock in a Grid and applying the EntranceThemeTransition to the Grid, but the same effect occurs on the TextBlock. The animation plays (slides the TextBlock in) and when the end of the path is hit, the RenderTransform is applied and the TextBlock "teleports" to the Translation offset defined in the RenderTransform.

Comment: How about applying the transition to the tb, but the transform to the grid?

Comment: Nope, same thing. I put the animation on the TextBlock and the RenderTransform on the Grid, but the same thing happens. TextBlock slides into place and then snaps to the Translation point.

Comment: Another option then is to just use Margins to adjust the position of the TextBlock. In your case you would set Margin="-2,8,2,-8".

Comment: Filip, I'll try your suggestions when I get a chance and update accordingly. Thanks for the responses.