# Adding Stationary New Items/Shapes To UI - Windows Store App

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I'm sure this issue must have a very straightforward answer but I can't seem to find it. Any help is much appreciated.

Whenever a new item is added to the UI, either at runtime or dynamically once the program is running, it slides into view to reach its position (with inertia). Only when it reaches that point are certain properties applied: like transform properties or opacity values. For example, if a rectangle set to 50% opacity is added when a button is tapped, it will slide onto the screen about 30 points from its actual position at 100% opacity, reach the correct position and then change to the correct 50% opacity.

I would like to be able to turn off this default behavior so the rectangle appears immediately at the correct position with all the properties set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that I'm asking two separate questions and that both have been answered on this site (links below).

Individual objects can be targeted using the Transitions property under Miscellaneous in Visual Studio 2012.

[How to remove EntranceThemeTransition from object or container in Windows 8 Store Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820097/how-to-remove-entrancethemetransition-from-object-or-container-in-windows-8-stor)

[RenderTransform occurs after EntranceThemeTransition on a TextBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435721/rendertransform-occurs-after-entrancethemetransition-on-a-textblock)